# useEffect in parent component and setState in context

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I can't find solution for my problem so I decided to ask here. I have component that in useEffect calling function in provided context with string value as parameter and in return function it will call it again, but with different string. That function (in context) compare saved string in state and provided string as argument and if its not same, it will change state. My problem is quick unmounting component (so return function in useEffect is called) and rerender (so classic useEffect is called again), but in context it didnt change state yet... so I am comparing old values.  Thank you very much for answers.

I tried to use setTimeOut in useEffect and its working but its not nice solution. I am looking for something better.

EDIT:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    layout.setBackArrowUrl('/projects/list');
    if (location.state && location.state.showArrow) {
      layout.setLeftContent(
        '/projects/project/monitor',
        <RecentProjectsList recentMode='search' />,
      );
      layout.setBackArrowUrlSub('/projects/list');
    } else {
      layout.setLeftContent('/projects/project/monitor', <RecentProjectsList recentMode='visit' />);
      layout.setBackArrowUrlSub('');
    }
    return () => {
      layout.setBackArrowUrl('');
      layout.setLeftContent('/projects/project/monitor/unmount', <React.Fragment />);
    };
  }, []);
```

and second part in other file creating context

```
setLeftContent = (code, leftDrawerContent) => {
    const { leftContentCode } = this.state;
    if (code !== leftContentCode) {
      this.setState({ leftDrawerContent, leftContentCode: code });
    }

  };
```

both files are really big, so im sharing just importing functions. So hopefully this help.

Comment: Hey, rather than explain your problems only, share the code what you are doing.
With this way, everybody can understand your problems and help well.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you please include a code snippet to your question for us to better understand what your intent is, how far you went and what blocks you. This code snippet will then serve as a basis for someone to answer.

Comment: Hi, your question looks a bit unclear. I recommend to provide a minimal working code example (i.e. Stackblitz). As for subject - you can check nice guide of it [here](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-context-and-usecontext/).

Comment: Hi, sure, i inserted it in question edit part. Thank you guys :)

Comment: As i mentioned my problem before - my useEffect is unmount and immediately mount again which will result in two calls setLeftContent, that for first time will change state, but second time wont, because there is still old value - it didnt proceed last value change

Comment: States in react are poorly suited to store data in them since you never know if there are pending updates and therefore have to consider every value (possibly) outdated. in Function components you could move your condition into an update function `setState(oldState => condition? newState: oldState)` but in class components `this.setState()` will *always* trigger a rerender even if you don't pass any value or return the old state. Take a look at the [shouldComponentUpdate()](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) livecycle method for that.

Comment: Or maybe you could debounce `setLeftContent` so that out of the three state updates *(mount, unmount, remount)* only the last update is executed.